# Jquery Ajax url variable not retrieving properly

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

```
    $.ajax({
dataType : "html" ,
url: "jquery-loadMoreComments.php?lastComment="+ $(".postedComment:last").attr('id')&"section="+'.$sid.',   
success: function(html) {
```

I am having this ajax request from one file to other and I am retrieving the url variable in other file like this

```
$filtered = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "lastComment", FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
$filtered1 = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "section", FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
```

The first variable gets retrieved properly but the second variable is not getting to the other file. And `$sid` is retrieved by the first file from the url and then is sent via ajax to the second file to continue the request.

I changed the url to this

```
    url: "jquery-loadMoreComments.php?lastComment="+ $(".postedComment:last").attr('id'),section: '<?= $sid ; ?>',
```

then in the second php file to retrieve the `$sid` I have written this

```
$filtered = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "section", FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
```

but still it is not executing . I think the `$sid` variable is not passed properly. In the first php file I have not written any code to pass the variabl `$sid`, how can I do that.

Comment: can you explain ? I think there is some problem in tha ajax call

Comment: Do yourself a favor, declare your query string parameters before the ajax call, it will make your ajax url parameter a lot cleaner and easier to read

Comment: That url string is invalid. Check your concatenation.

Comment: @Rahul Rawat: "I think" -- you can continue *guessing* or use `var_dump($_GET);` to be *sure*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the problem is with `'.$sid'` at the end of the URL. You're probably expecting that to be replaced with the PHP variable, but this doesn't look like a context where replacement happens.

To make the replacement happen, you need to get back into PHP processing mode, e.g.

```
"&section=<?= $sid ?>",
```

Also, rather than constructing the URL parameters by concatenating strings, use the `data:` parameter to `$.ajax` and supply an object. jQuery will construct the parameter string automatically for you, with proper URL-encoding. So it should be:

```
$.ajax({
    dataType : "html" ,
    url: "jquery-loadMoreComments.php",
    data: {
        lastComment: $(".postedComment:last").attr("id"),
        section: '<?= $sid ?>'
    },
    success: function(html) {
```

Comment: Can I directly send the value of a variable from one Php file to other php file using $_POST superglobal or something like that.

Comment: I don't know what data type `$sid` is. If it's a number, you don't need the quotes around it (although they won't hurt, since they'll end up the same in the URL).

Comment: and how will I pass the value to the javascript file from the php file?

Comment: That's what `<?= $sid ?>` does. It's short for `<?php echo $sid; ?>`.

Comment: You're mixing up paradigms. You can't use `section: '<?= $sid ?>'` if it's not in the `data:` parameter.

Comment: Okay so I have a php file which has a $sid variable and I want to pass it to another php file using ajax. Can you tell me how to do this.

Comment: I showed you two ways in my answer. Then you took parts of each and mixed them together into something that won't work.

Comment: using $.ajax({
    dataType : "html" ,
    url: "jquery-loadMoreComments.php",
    data: {
        lastComment: $(".postedComment:last").attr("id"),
        section: '<?= $sid ?>'
    },
    success: function(html) {
it give an exception and the results are not executed .

Comment: What is the exception? This Javascript is being created by the PHP script with the `$sid` variable, right? Have you looked at the generated Javascript in Firebug?